# Removal of ex partner from help to buy scheme and mortgage

Tags: united-kingdom, mortgage, first-time-home-buyer, title

### Context

Mortgage and Help To Buy UK scheme is in two names. The house was purchased just over two years ago. So still some time before the equity loan repayments, for the Help To Buy kick in.

I have been solely paying the mortgage and all bills for over 6 months now.

### Goal

Removing ex partner from title deeds, mortgage and help to buy scheme. To become the sole owner of the house.

### What I do know

GOV.UK have little information regarding these matters.

- The homeowners named on the equity loan must be the same as those on the repayment mortgage
- Any homeowner that stays on the contract will need to show that they can afford it
- A solicitor must be involved

### What I would like to learn more about

- Get more information about contacting the Help To Buy equity loan administrator. Can they be contacted via logging into the [Help To Buy portal](https://portal.helptobuyagent3.org.uk/Login)?
- Understanding the relationship between a bank and the equity loan administrators. How much middle man work is involved?
- I understand that I must prove to the bank that I can afford the mortgage alone. Will I need to also prove this to help to buy. Or will this information be "automatically" passed between these two parties?
- At what point should I involve a solicitor? I am operating on the assumption, it should be right away

I was unable to find a great deal of useful information and people in a similar situation. I imagine this would be due to a solicitor being involved at this point, therefore all the relevant tips go "offline"

Comment: That appears to be multiple, though related, questions. Stack Exchange works better when we focus on one question at a time. If suggest editing this to focus on the one you care most about, then asking the others separately. But legal advice is outside our remit, and most of what you're asking seems to start with "talk to a lawyer".